# Problem with NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, filesystems

I am trying to work directories. Unfortunately i get a non-writeable directory when I run NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. What I get is:

> /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Documents

When I run other people's examples I get:

> /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/6958D21C-C94B-4843-9EF1-70406D0CA3A3/Documents

which is writeable.

The snippet of the code used is

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(documentsDirectory);
```

What do I need to do allow me to get the same long directory structure?

Answer (score 4):

That long path with the GUID *is* the documents path for your app, and is expected behavior.

Not sure what your code looks like, but getting the path to your app's document directory should be something like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

(From [Mark/LaMarche](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263) p. 331)

Comment: That's what I have done. Here is the portion. I have also written a skeleton app from scratch and I get the same problem.

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(documentsDirectory);

Comment: I have clarified my question with the code snippet. This is a real mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

since it searches for the "object at index:0"

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

there could be a directory starting with a letter smaller than "d" for documents. Which becomes the "object at index:0". I know this might not be possible but It could be true as well.